# how to refresh recyclerview after making some change on sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

My app has recyclerview in fragment and when I click one of the list inside recyclerview, on the next page, there is check button that I can update a value on sqlite database. With this updating, I can change order of list of recyclerview. Since sqlite database is not like firebase addlistener. It can not refresh database right away.
Is there any way to refresh list of recyclerview right away when I click back button to go to recyclerview page?
I googled and found some similar questions but I couldn't resolve my issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package com.donghyouny.biblecard;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BibleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BibleAdapter.BibleViewHolder> {

    private  ArrayList<Bible> arrayList;
    private  Context context;
    private OnVerseItemClickListener listener;


    public BibleAdapter(ArrayList<Bible> arrayList, Context context) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnVerseItemClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BibleAdapter.BibleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.verse_item, parent, false);
        BibleViewHolder holder = new BibleViewHolder(view, listener);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BibleAdapter.BibleViewHolder holder, int position) {

      /* RequestOptions reqOpt = RequestOptions
                .fitCenterTransform()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .override(140,100);


                   .apply(reqOpt)
*/

        Glide.with(holder.imageView)
                .load(arrayList.get(position).getImage())
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                .into(holder.imageView);

        //Glide.with(PersonInfoActivity.this).load(R.drawable.standard_profile).apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop()).into(imageView);
       // holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.church);


        holder.bibleType.setText(arrayList.get(position).getBibleType());
        holder.content.setText(arrayList.get(position).getContent());
        holder.verse.setText(arrayList.get(position).getVerse());



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (arrayList!=null? arrayList.size():0);
    }


    public void setList(ArrayList<Bible> list ) { this.arrayList = list; }






    public class BibleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView bibleType;
        TextView verse;
        TextView content;
        ImageView save;

        public BibleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnVerseItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            this.bibleType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bibleType);
            this.content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);
            this.verse = itemView.findViewById(R.id.verse);
            this.save = itemView.findViewById(R.id.save);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(listener != null){
                        listener.onItemClick(BibleViewHolder.this, v, position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    }
}
```

```
 Cursor readAllData(String value){
        Log.d("readData", "test");
        String query = "select Id,BibleType, Verse, Content, Num, CNum, CheckNum, Image, datetime(TimeStamp) as MyDate  from bible where CNum=" + "(select Id from category where CategoryName='" + value + "') order by TimeStamp asc";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if(db != null){
            Log.d("readData1","test");
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

```
void updateData(Bible bible){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        String id = String.valueOf(bible.getId());
        cv.put(COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));

        long result = db.update(TABLE_BIBLE, cv, "Id=?", new String[]{id});
        if(result == -1){

        }else {
           Log.d("update", "success")
        }

    }
```

```
package com.donghyouny.biblecard;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import static com.donghyouny.biblecard.SplashActivity.ROOT_DIR;


public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public static final String VERSE_DATA = "data";
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private BibleAdapter adapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager; //for sorting
    private ArrayList<Bible> bList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Connection conn;
    private Statement stmt;
    private ResultSet rs, rs2;
    private Bible bible;
    private String value;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    public Fragment1(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Fragment1(){

    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

        conn = Utiles.dbConnection();


       MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
       Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData(value);
       while(cursor.moveToNext()){
           bible = new Bible();
           Log.d("cursorid", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0)));
           bible.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
           bible.setBibleType(cursor.getString(1));
           bible.setVerse(cursor.getString(2));
           bible.setContent(cursor.getString(3));
           bible.setNum(cursor.getInt(4));
           bible.setCnum(cursor.getInt(5));
           bible.setCheckNum(cursor.getInt(6));
           bible.setImage(cursor.getBlob(7));
           bible.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(8));
           bList.add(bible);
       }

        Log.d("blist", bList.toString());
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        adapter = new BibleAdapter(bList, getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnVerseItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(BibleAdapter.BibleViewHolder holder, View view, final int position) {     //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "num"+adapter.getItemCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            // Step 1: Display the interstitial
                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                            // Step 2: Attach an AdListener
                            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAdClosed() {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), VerseActivity.class);
                                    Log.d("bible33", bList.get(position).toString());
                                    intent.putExtra("bible", bList.get(position));
                                    intent.putExtra("category", value);
                                    Log.d("bibleIntent", bible.toString());

                                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), VerseActivity.class);
                            Log.d("bible33", bList.get(position).toString());
                            intent.putExtra("bible", bList.get(position));
                            intent.putExtra("category", value);
                            Log.d("bibleIntent", bible.toString());

                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                        }


                    }
        });


        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;
    }




    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_actions, menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.save_folder:

                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SaveActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
                return true;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    }
}
```

```
package com.donghyouny.biblecard;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.RoundedCorners;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static com.donghyouny.biblecard.SplashActivity.ROOT_DIR;

public class VerseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView bibleType;
    private TextView verse;
    private TextView content;
    public Bible bible;

    private ImageView save, check;


    private String category;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private Statement stmt;
    private ResultSet rs;
    private SharedPreferences checkDialog;
    private SharedPreferences saveDialog;
    private SharedPreferences shareDialog;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private boolean flag=true;
    private Fragment1 fragment1;

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verse);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adbanner);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        fragment1 = new Fragment1();
        bibleType = findViewById(R.id.bibleType);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        verse = findViewById(R.id.verse);
        content = findViewById(R.id.content);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        save = findViewById(R.id.save);
        check = findViewById(R.id.check);
        //   category = findViewById(R.id.category);
        //key = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");

        if((getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bible")!=null)&& (getIntent().getStringExtra("category")!=null)){
            Log.d("nocard", "Test");

            bible = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bible");
            category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");
            Log.d("!!!bible", bible.toString());


            display();



        }else if((getIntent().getParcelableExtra("cardBible")!=null)&& (getIntent().getStringExtra("cName")!=null)){
            Log.d("cardop", "test");
            check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)save.getLayoutParams();
            //lp.rightMargin=0;
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            save.setLayoutParams(lp);
            bible = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("cardBible");
            //Log.d("bible.key", bible.getKey());
            category = getIntent().getStringExtra("cName");
            display();

        }





        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkDialog = getSharedPreferences("checkDialog", MODE_PRIVATE);
                boolean isFirstTime = checkDialog.getBoolean("firstTime", true);
                if (isFirstTime) {
                    checkDialogPopup();
                } else {
                    checkMethod(bible);
                }
            }
        });

    }
    private void checkMethod(Bible bible) {
        MyDatabaseHelper db = new MyDatabaseHelper(VerseActivity.this);
        db.updateData(bible);

        }
    private void checkDialogPopup() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
        builder.setTitle("Check button");
        builder.setMessage("You can not undo this button");
        builder.setPositiveButton("예",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You click 'yes'",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        checkMethod(bible);
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Don't show this message",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = checkDialog.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
                        editor.commit();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Don't want to see this message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }





    double getScreenInches() {

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;
        double wi = (double) width / (double) dm.xdpi;
        double hi = (double) height / (double) dm.ydpi;
        double x = Math.pow(wi, 2);
        double y = Math.pow(hi, 2);
        double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);

        return screenInches;
    }
    private void display(){
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = metrics.widthPixels;
        params.height = (int)(metrics.heightPixels/2.8);
        Log.d("width", String.valueOf(params.width));
        Log.d("height", String.valueOf(params.height));
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);


        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(bible.getImage()).apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop()).into(imageView);
        //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.church);
        bibleType.setText(bible.getBibleType().toString());
        verse.setText(bible.getVerse().toString());
        content.setText(bible.getContent().toString());

        Log.d("content", bible.getContent().toString());
        int inch = (int)( getScreenInches()+0.5 );
        Log.d("inch", String.valueOf(3*inch));
        //content.setTextSize(3*inch);
        toolbar.setTitle(category);







   }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the data from the database and list process in a separate function. you can call this function in the onResume() method. I think you should research the android life cycle. Reference Link is : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

According to the definition in the documentation

onResume() : When the activity enters the Resumed state, it comes to the foreground, and then the system invokes the onResume() callback. This is the state in which the app interacts with the user. The app stays in this state until something happens to take focus away from the app. Such an event might be, for instance, receiving a phone call, the user’s navigating to another activity, or the device screen’s turning off.

For example:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

conn = Utiles.dbConnection();

recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
//recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
adapter = new BibleAdapter(bList, getContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnVerseItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(BibleAdapter.BibleViewHolder holder, View view, final int position) {     //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "num"+adapter.getItemCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    // Step 1: Display the interstitial
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                    // Step 2: Attach an AdListener
                    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdClosed() {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), VerseActivity.class);
                            Log.d("bible33", bList.get(position).toString());
                            intent.putExtra("bible", bList.get(position));
                            intent.putExtra("category", value);
                            Log.d("bibleIntent", bible.toString());

                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), VerseActivity.class);
                    Log.d("bible33", bList.get(position).toString());
                    intent.putExtra("bible", bList.get(position));
                    intent.putExtra("category", value);
                    Log.d("bibleIntent", bible.toString());

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }


            }
});


setHasOptionsMenu(true);
return rootView;
```

}

```
public void fetchDataFromSqliteDatabase() {
    MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData(value);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        bible = new Bible();
        Log.d("cursorid", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0)));
        bible.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        bible.setBibleType(cursor.getString(1));
        bible.setVerse(cursor.getString(2));
        bible.setContent(cursor.getString(3));
        bible.setNum(cursor.getInt(4));
        bible.setCnum(cursor.getInt(5));
        bible.setCheckNum(cursor.getInt(6));
        bible.setImage(cursor.getBlob(7));
        bible.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(8));
        bList.add(bible);
    }
    adapter.setList(bList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

then you can call it from onResume()

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    fetchDataFromSqliteDatabase();
}
```

also you should create a new method named setList. you should give this method a list as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried like this but it didn't work and I edited my question to show which method to display all the list. @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData(value);
       
    }

Comment: I think, it should work. inside fetchDataFromSqliteDatabase method, We fetch all data and set all data to a list. then we set list to setList method of adapter.after then we refresh list with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Comment: I am getting an error on this line: adapter.setList(bList); setList doesn't recognize.

Comment: You have to create a new method named setList() inside adapter.

Comment: like this; 
public void setList(ArrayList<Bible> list )  { this.list = list; }

Comment: When I click check button and click back button, on recycleview, it duplicate the list but it did change order. I edited my post to add adapter. I think I have arraylist again there public BibleAdapter(ArrayList<Bible> arrayList, Context context) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

Comment: Thank you for your help! It did change the order. but I still have duplicates. Do you know what might be the issue....?

Comment: I added   bList.clear(); in the beginning of fetchDataFromSqliteDatabase method  and it worked. and later I found out that I don't need adapter.setList(bList); Thank you for your help!